# ServiceStack's Config.AdminAuthSecret is not working

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, servicestack

I have a service using the **Authorize** attribute I would like to use ServiceStack's **AdminAuthSecret** feature but it isn't working.

I have set the  **AdminAuthSecret** as shown below:

```
public void Configure(Container container, IAppHost host)
        {
            // more code...
            host.Config.AdminAuthSecret = "9999";
            // more code...
        }
```

Therefore I have checked out ServiceStack's source code in order to debug it and I have set a breakpoint at following place:

**ServiceStackHost class:**

```
 public bool HasValidAuthSecret(IRequest httpReq)
        {
            if (Config.AdminAuthSecret != null)
            {
                var authSecret = httpReq.GetParam("authsecret");
                return authSecret == Config.AdminAuthSecret;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

But the breakpoint never hits. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: the API to set the configuration in ServiceStack is:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    AdminAuthSecret = "9999"
});
```

`Config.AdminAuthSecret` was used to by-pass Services protected with RequiredRole and RequiredPermission attributes. I've just extended it to by-pass `[Authenticate]` Services as well [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/b41e750d3a9d2be409620940e5b6e39c168d02f0) which will be available from v4.0.39+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).